# jQuery Mobile: Content doesn't load properly after changePage

Tags: jquery-mobile

My application has a button (on app.html) that leads to a new page with a navbar (app2.html). The Navigation has an internal link (Toolbar 2) that should show the internal div "page2".

When coming from the button with changePage() it is not able to display the content when clicking on the navigation. It seems like the reloadPage is not working.

app.html looks like this:

```
<body>
    <!-- Home -->
    <div data-role="page" id="page3">
        <div data-role="content">
            <a id="asdf" data-role="button" name="asdf">
                Button
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        $('#asdf').click(function(){

            $.mobile.changePage('app2.html', {transition: "slidedown", reloadPage: true, changeHash: true });

            });

    </script>
</body>
```

This is my app2.html:

```
<body>
    <!-- Home -->
    <div data-role="page" id="page1">
        <div data-role="content">
            <div id="navigation" data-role="navbar" data-iconpos="right">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="app.html" data-theme="" data-icon="">
                            Toolbar1
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#page2" data-theme="" data-icon="check">
                            toolbar 2
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="app.html" data-theme="" data-icon="">
                            Toolbar 3
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="page" id="page2">
        <div data-role="content">
            <div data-role="header">
                <h3>asdfasd</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 </body>
```

Where's the problem? I'm using jQuerymobile 1.1.1 with jQuery 1.7.1.

Here are the files:
[app.html](http://nopaste.me/paste/123233746150784b48278d0)
[app2.html](http://nopaste.me/paste/1094931076507844ba22717)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have two jQuery Mobile pages in the second page. When you click on the link in app.html, it will do an ajax request to app2.html to get the data-role="page" and it expects only in the html file. You should read up on the difference between a [single page template](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/page-template.html) and a [multi-page template](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/multipage-template.html).

You can find more in the docs, look for ["Linking within a multi-page document"](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/page-links.html).

tl;dr: You either need to put all the pages in one HTML file and link to the id or put all the pages in separate HTML files and link to the file.

Comment: So how should I do it that it shows the right div when clicking on the navbar?

Comment: @cr8z3r Either make all the pages their own HTML document, or place all the pages into a single HTML document, to do both you will have to use a plugin (not sure if it exists) or write custom code that grabs all `data-role="page"` elements from external documents rather than just the first one.

Comment: I checked the example for a multi-page template and I'm doing exactly that. There are also 2 pages.

Comment: @cr8z3r You can't mix single-page templates and multi-page templates. Either use one or the other, when you link to an external document, only the first `data-role="page"` element is brought-into the current DOM.